# Integration Test for Jira Is Not Running ( Failed to execute goal com.atlassian.maven.plugins:maven-jira-plugin:6.2.3:integration-test)

Tags: spring, maven, osgi, integration-testing, jira

I am trying to execute an integration test for my jira plugin, however, the installation of the component fails for some reason.

Do you have any suggestions where to dig?

Following is the log

```
[INFO] Starting Atlassian Spring Byte Code
> Scanner... [INFO]  [ERROR] Found a type
> [com.atlassian.plugin.spring.scanner.annotation.imports.RefappImport]
> annotated as a component, but the type is not a concrete class. NOT
> adding to index file!! [ERROR] Found a type
> [com.atlassian.plugin.spring.scanner.annotation.imports.JiraImport]
> annotated as a component, but the type is not a concrete class. NOT
> adding to index file!! [ERROR] Found a type
> [com.atlassian.plugin.spring.scanner.annotation.imports.ConfluenceImport]
> annotated as a component, but the type is not a concrete class. NOT
> adding to index file!! [ERROR] Found a type
> [com.atlassian.plugin.spring.scanner.annotation.export.ModuleType]
> annotated as a component, but the type is not a concrete class. NOT
> adding to index file!! [ERROR] Found a type
> [com.atlassian.plugin.spring.scanner.annotation.component.RefappComponent]
> annotated as a component, but the type is not a concrete class. NOT
> adding to index file!! [ERROR] Found a type
> [com.atlassian.plugin.spring.scanner.annotation.component.JiraComponent]
> annotated as a component, but the type is not a concrete class. NOT
> adding to index file!! [ERROR] Found a type
> [com.atlassian.plugin.spring.scanner.annotation.component.ConfluenceComponent]
> annotated as a component, but the type is not a concrete class. NOT
> adding to index file!! [ERROR] Found a type
> [com.atlassian.plugin.spring.scanner.annotation.component.ClasspathComponent]
> annotated as a component, but the type is not a concrete class. NOT
> adding to index file!! [INFO]  [INFO]  Analysis ran in 243 ms. [INFO] 
> Encountered 1235 total classes [INFO]  Processed 9 annotated classes
> [INFO]  [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.1:testResources
> (default-testResources) @ jira --- [WARNING] Using platform encoding
> (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform
> dependent! [INFO] Copying 2 resources [INFO]  [INFO] ---
> maven-jira-plugin:6.2.3:filter-test-plugin-descriptor
> (default-filter-test-plugin-descriptor) @ jira --- [INFO] Using
> 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources. [INFO] Copying 1 resource
> [INFO]  [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile
> (default-testCompile) @ jira --- [INFO] Nothing to compile - all
> classes are up to date [INFO]  [INFO] ---
> maven-jira-plugin:6.2.3:unit-test (default-unit-test) @ jira ---
> [INFO] Surefire report directory:
> /Users/strygul/dcm/jira-module/target/surefire-reports
> 
> -------------------------------------------------------  T E S T S
> ------------------------------------------------------- Running ut.com.idalko.dcm.customfield.NextRevisionNumberFieldTypeTest Tests
> run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.325 sec
> Running ut.com.idalko.dcm.helpers.UtilTest Tests run: 1, Failures: 0,
> Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.001 sec Running
> ut.com.idalko.dcm.model.articlerevision.ArticleRevisionInputParamsImplTest
> Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 sec

> [INFO]  [INFO] --- maven-jira-plugin:6.2.3:copy-bundled-dependencies
> (default-copy-bundled-dependencies) @ jira --- [INFO]
> gson-2.2.2-atlassian-1.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> jira-issue-link-confluence-plugin-7.1.6.jar already exists in
> destination. [INFO] httpcore-4.4.1.jar already exists in destination.
> [INFO] commons-codec-1.9.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> atlassian-spring-scanner-runtime-1.2.6.jar already exists in
> destination. [INFO] httpclient-4.4.1.jar already exists in
> destination. [INFO] atlassian-spring-scanner-annotation-1.2.6.jar
> already exists in destination. [INFO]  [INFO] ---
> maven-jira-plugin:6.2.3:copy-test-bundled-dependencies
> (default-copy-test-bundled-dependencies) @ jira --- [INFO]
> hibernate-2.1.8-atlassian.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> bcprov-jdk15on-1.50.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> jcip-annotations-1.0.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> atlassian-plugins-osgi-testrunner-1.2.3.jar already exists in
> destination. [INFO] spring-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar already exists in
> destination. [INFO] atlassian-application-api-1.2.jar already exists
> in destination. [INFO] atlassian-vcache-internal-core-0.7.0.jar
> already exists in destination. [INFO] commons-compress-1.8.1.jar
> already exists in destination. [INFO] atlassian-core-user-5.0.6.jar
> already exists in destination. [INFO] atlassian-gzipfilter-3.0.0.jar
> already exists in destination. [INFO] webwork-1.4-atlassian-30.jar
> already exists in destination. [INFO]
> atlassian-plugins-webresource-api-3.5.9.jar already exists in
> destination. [INFO] atlassian-profiling-1.9.jar already exists in
> destination. [INFO] log4j2-stacktrace-origins-2.2-atlassian-2.jar
> already exists in destination. [INFO] struts-1.2.9.jar already exists
> in destination. [INFO] batik-parser-1.7.jar already exists in
> destination. [INFO] atlassian-plugin-point-safety-0.10.jar already
> exists in destination. [INFO] xml-apis-ext-1.3.04.jar already exists
> in destination. [INFO] sslext-1.2-0.jar already exists in destination.
> [INFO] jotm-iiop_stubs-1.4.3.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> atlassian-p4package-2007.12.14.jar already exists in destination.
> [INFO] oscore-2.2.7-atlassian-1.jar already exists in destination.
> [INFO] beehive-single-node-0.2.jar already exists in destination.
> [INFO] velocity-1.4.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> atlassian-util-concurrent-2.6.2.jar already exists in destination.
> [INFO] javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar already exists in destination.
> [INFO] mysema-commons-lang-0.2.4.jar already exists in destination.
> [INFO] csv-20.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> commons-codec-1.9.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> beehive-core-0.2.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> sal-api-3.0.3.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> jsoup-1.8.3.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> blobstore-client-api-1.3.0.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> atlassian-logging-2.15.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> jzlib-1.0.5.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> common-lang-3.2.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> crowd-core-tiny-2.8.3.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> xml-apis-1.3.04.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> jira-issue-link-confluence-plugin-7.1.6.jar already exists in
> destination. [INFO] commons-fileupload-1.3.1.jar already exists in
> destination. [INFO] spring-data-commons-1.6.1.RELEASE.jar already
> exists in destination. [INFO] commons-validator-1.4.0.jar already
> exists in destination. [INFO] jaxb-api-2.1.jar already exists in
> destination. [INFO] fugue-2.6.0.jar already exists in destination.
> [INFO] guava-retrying-1.0.7.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> applinks-spi-5.0.7.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> atlassian-scheduler-caesium-1.3.0.jar already exists in destination.
> [INFO] crowd-integration-api-2.8.3.jar already exists in destination.
> [INFO] nekohtml-1.9.19.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> jfreechart-1.0.13.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> carol-properties-1.5.2.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> urlrewritefilter-4.0.3.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> crowd-persistence-2.8.3.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> atlassian-servlet-api-2.0.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> jaxb-impl-2.2.1.1.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> commons-digester-1.4.1.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> jstyleparser-1.16-atlassian-1.jar already exists in destination.
> [INFO] crowd-ldap-2.8.3.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> jersey-json-1.8-atlassian-16.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> jira-api-7.1.6.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> commons-jrcs-diff-0.1.7.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> commons-lang-2.6.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> atlassian-plugins-api-4.1.0-m002.jar already exists in destination.
> [INFO] atlassian-gadgets-spi-4.2.0.jar already exists in destination.
> [INFO] antlr-2.7.2.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> xfire-aegis-1.2.6.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> common-image-3.2.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> atlassian-trusted-apps-seraph-integration-4.1.0.jar already exists in
> destination. [INFO] activation-1.1.1.jar already exists in
> destination. [INFO] atlassian-cache-common-impl-2.11.1.jar already
> exists in destination. [INFO] jsr311-api-1.1.1.jar already exists in
> destination. [INFO] jndi-1.2.1.jar already exists in destination.
> [INFO] httpcore-4.4.1.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> log4j-1.2.16.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> jcommon-1.0.8.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> package-scanner-0.9.5.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> velocity-dep-1.4.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> spring-tx-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> xfire-core-1.2.6.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> atlassian-core-thumbnail-5.0.6.jar already exists in destination.
> [INFO] jcaptcha-2.0-alpha-1.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> jersey-server-1.8-atlassian-16.jar already exists in destination.
> [INFO] querydsl-sql-4.0.7.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> spymemcached-2.12.0.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> jersey-core-1.8-atlassian-16.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> joda-time-2.8.2.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> filters-2.0.235.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> batik-anim-1.7.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> atlassian-cache-memory-2.11.1.jar already exists in destination.
> [INFO] atlassian-collectors-util-0.10.jar already exists in
> destination. [INFO] powermock-api-support-1.6.2.jar already exists in
> destination. [INFO] activeobjects-dbex-1.1.0.jar already exists in
> destination. [INFO] atlassian-http-1.1.1.jar already exists in
> destination. [INFO] jta-1.0.1.jar already exists in destination.
> [INFO] xstream-1.4.8.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> spring-jdbc-2.0.6.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> atlassian-vcache-internal-memcached-0.7.0.jar already exists in
> destination. [INFO] batik-script-1.7.jar already exists in
> destination. [INFO] imageio-core-3.2.jar already exists in
> destination. [INFO] crowd-events-2.8.3.jar already exists in
> destination. [INFO] batik-bridge-1.7.jar already exists in
> destination. [INFO] dom4j-1.4.jar already exists in destination.
> [INFO] com.atlassian.jersey-library-2.9.17.pom already exists in
> destination. [INFO] hibernate-validator-4.0.2.GA.jar already exists in
> destination. [INFO] jul-to-slf4j-1.7.9.jar already exists in
> destination. [INFO] httpclient-4.4.1.jar already exists in
> destination. [INFO] atlassian-vcache-internal-api-0.7.0.jar already
> exists in destination. [INFO] atlassian-localhost-1.1.0.jar already
> exists in destination. [INFO] spring-ldap-core-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar
> already exists in destination. [INFO] sal-trust-api-3.0.3.jar already
> exists in destination. [INFO] slf4j-log4j12-1.7.9.jar already exists
> in destination. [INFO] crowd-remote-2.8.3.jar already exists in
> destination. [INFO] javax.mail-1.5.4.jar already exists in
> destination. [INFO] atlassian-vcache-internal-legacy-0.7.0.jar already
> exists in destination. [INFO] atlassian-cache-ehcache-2.11.1.jar
> already exists in destination. [INFO]
> atlassian-flushable-gzipoutputstream-1.1.jar already exists in
> destination. [INFO] powermock-core-1.6.2.jar already exists in
> destination. [INFO] biz.aQute.bndlib-2.4.1.jar already exists in
> destination. [INFO] commons-logging-1.0.4.jar already exists in
> destination. [INFO] spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar already exists in
> destination. [INFO] jtidy-r8-20050104.jar already exists in
> destination. [INFO] crowd-api-2.8.3.jar already exists in destination.
> [INFO] xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> objenesis-2.1.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> jackson-xc-1.9.1.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> lucene-analyzers-3.3.0.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> activeobjects-test-1.1.0.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> httpclient-cache-4.4.1.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> lucene-core-3.3.0-atlassian-1.jar already exists in destination.
> [INFO] atlassian-plugins-core-4.1.0-m002.jar already exists in
> destination. [INFO] atlassian-secure-xml-3.2.3.jar already exists in
> destination. [INFO] commons-httpclient-3.1-atlassian-2.jar already
> exists in destination. [INFO] propertyset-1.5.jar already exists in
> destination. [INFO] crowd-server-api-2.8.3.jar already exists in
> destination. [INFO] commons-collections-3.2.2.jar already exists in
> destination. [INFO] commons-dbcp2-2.1.jar already exists in
> destination. [INFO] atlassian-image-consumer-1.0.1.jar already exists
> in destination. [INFO] gson-2.2.2-atlassian-1.jar already exists in
> destination. [INFO] atlassian-secure-random-3.2.3.jar already exists
> in destination. [INFO] spring-hibernate2-2.0.6.jar already exists in
> destination. [INFO] atlassian-plugins-schema-4.1.0-m002.jar already
> exists in destination. [INFO] xpp3-1.1.4c.jar already exists in
> destination. [INFO] activeobjects-test-1.1.0.jar already exists in
> destination. [INFO] beehive-db-0.2.jar already exists in destination.
> [INFO] atlassian-plugins-webresource-common-4.1.0-m002.jar already
> exists in destination. [INFO] botocss-core-6.2.jar already exists in
> destination. [INFO] aopalliance-1.0.jar already exists in destination.
> [INFO] atlassian-plugins-servlet-4.1.0-m002.jar already exists in
> destination. [INFO] commons-beanutils-1.6.1.jar already exists in
> destination. [INFO] atlassian-spring-scanner-runtime-1.2.6.jar already
> exists in destination. [INFO] activeobjects-core-1.1.0.jar already
> exists in destination. [INFO] crowd-query-language-2.8.3.jar already
> exists in destination. [INFO]
> org.apache.servicemix.bundles.javax-inject-1_2.jar already exists in
> destination. [INFO] atlassian-plugins-eventlistener-4.1.0-m002.jar
> already exists in destination. [INFO] sitemesh-2.5-atlassian-11.jar
> already exists in destination. [INFO] batik-gvt-1.7.jar already exists
> in destination. [INFO] velocity-htmlsafe-1.4.jar already exists in
> destination. [INFO] mockito-core-1.10.19.jar already exists in
> destination. [INFO] jcaptcha-api-2.0-alpha-1.jar already exists in
> destination. [INFO] wsdl4j-1.6.1.jar already exists in destination.
> [INFO] atlassian-seraph-3.0.3.jar already exists in destination.
> [INFO] jonas_timer-1.4.3.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> stax2-api-3.1.0.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> beehive-api-0.2.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> commons-configuration-1.0.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> upm-api-2.15.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> batik-svg-dom-1.7.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> atlassian-annotations-0.16.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> imageio-metadata-3.2.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> atlassian-event-2.3.5.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> common-io-3.2.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> spring-expression-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar already exists in destination.
> [INFO] serializer-2.7.2.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> modz-detector-0.12.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> ots-jts-1.0.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> atlassian-rest-common-2.9.17.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> powermock-reflect-1.6.2.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> atlassian-core-5.0.6.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> embedded-crowd-spi-2.8.3.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> crowd-integration-seraph25-2.8.3.jar already exists in destination.
> [INFO] atlassian-config-0.15.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> wink-common-1.1.3-incubating.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> atlassian-trusted-apps-core-4.1.0.jar already exists in destination.
> [INFO] xalan-2.7.2.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> soy-template-renderer-api-4.3.0.jar already exists in destination.
> [INFO] atlassian-ip-3.0.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> slf4j-api-1.7.9.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> bsh-1.2b7.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> jira-issue-link-applinks-common-plugin-7.1.6.jar already exists in
> destination. [INFO] batik-dom-1.7.jar already exists in destination.
> [INFO] validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar already exists in destination.
> [INFO] atlassian-mail-2.5.16.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> spring-aop-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> jai_codec-1.1.3.jar already exists in destination. [INFO] bsf-2.2.jar
> already exists in destination. [INFO]
> atlassian-password-encoder-3.2.3.jar already exists in destination.
> [INFO] batik-codec-1.7.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> imageio-jpeg-3.2.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> jai_core-1.1.3.jar already exists in destination. [INFO] asm-5.0.3.jar
> already exists in destination. [INFO] jsr305-1.3.9.jar already exists
> in destination. [INFO] batik-css-1.7.jar already exists in
> destination. [INFO] atlassian-spring-scanner-annotation-1.2.6.jar
> already exists in destination. [INFO] atlassian-tenancy-api-1.4.0.jar
> already exists in destination. [INFO] picocontainer-2.14.3.jar already
> exists in destination. [INFO] commons-io-2.1.jar already exists in
> destination. [INFO] atlassian-oauth-api-2.0.2.jar already exists in
> destination. [INFO] imageio-tiff-3.2.jar already exists in
> destination. [INFO] jackson-core-asl-1.9.1.jar already exists in
> destination. [INFO] antlr-runtime-3.5.2.jar already exists in
> destination. [INFO] oro-2.0.7.jar already exists in destination.
> [INFO] atlassian-cookie-tools-3.2.3.jar already exists in destination.
> [INFO] atlassian-johnson-core-3.0.0.jar already exists in destination.
> [INFO] soy-template-renderer-plugin-api-4.3.0.jar already exists in
> destination. [INFO] carol-1.5.2.jar already exists in destination.
> [INFO] crowd-integration-client-common-2.8.3.jar already exists in
> destination. [INFO] applinks-api-5.0.7.jar already exists in
> destination. [INFO] pell-multipart-request-1.31.0.jar already exists
> in destination. [INFO] javax.inject-1.jar already exists in
> destination. [INFO] crowd-server-common-2.8.3.jar already exists in
> destination. [INFO] atlassian-gadgets-api-4.2.0.jar already exists in
> destination. [INFO] entityengine-share-1.2.3.jar already exists in
> destination. [INFO] jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.1.jar already exists in
> destination. [INFO] analytics-api-5.0.10.jar already exists in
> destination. [INFO] xapool-1.3.1.jar already exists in destination.
> [INFO] stax-api-1.0-2.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> guava-18.0.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> activeobjects-spi-1.1.5.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> woodstox-core-asl-4.1.0.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> crowd-integration-client-rest-2.8.3.jar already exists in destination.
> [INFO] atlassian-plugins-osgi-4.1.0-m002.jar already exists in
> destination. [INFO] applinks-host-5.0.7.jar already exists in
> destination. [INFO] entityengine-1.2.3.jar already exists in
> destination. [INFO] batik-ext-1.7.jar already exists in destination.
> [INFO] geronimo-annotation_1.1_spec-1.0.jar already exists in
> destination. [INFO] glue-5.0b2.jar already exists in destination.
> [INFO] atlassian-application-host-1.2.jar already exists in
> destination. [INFO] hamcrest-core-1.1.jar already exists in
> destination. [INFO] atlassian-cache-api-2.11.1.jar already exists in
> destination. [INFO] crowd-core-2.8.3.jar already exists in
> destination. [INFO] radeox-1.0b2-forked-22Apr2004.jar already exists
> in destination. [INFO] javassist-3.19.0-GA.jar already exists in
> destination. [INFO] spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar already exists in
> destination. [INFO] velocity-tools-1.3.jar already exists in
> destination. [INFO] activeobjects-plugin-1.1.0.jar already exists in
> destination. [INFO] embedded-crowd-core-2.8.3.jar already exists in
> destination. [INFO] h2-1.4.185.jar already exists in destination.
> [INFO] batik-util-1.7.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> atlassian-plugins-webresource-3.5.9.jar already exists in destination.
> [INFO] jira-core-7.1.6.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> atlassian-velocity-1.3.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> atlassian-jdk-utilities-0.4.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> atlassian-extras-3.1.2.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> commons-pool2-2.3.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> commons-pool-1.5.4.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> wstx-asl-3.2.4.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> jira-lucene-dmz-7.1.6.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> crowd-password-encoders-2.8.3.jar already exists in destination.
> [INFO] activeobjects-1.1.0.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> cglib-nodep-2.1_3.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> xmlpull-1.1.3.1.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> wink-client-1.1.3-incubating.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> atlassian-instrumentation-core-2.2.1.jar already exists in
> destination. [INFO] osworkflow-2.8.1.jar already exists in
> destination. [INFO] atlassian-plugins-webfragment-api-4.1.0.jar
> already exists in destination. [INFO] spring-web-2.0.6.jar already
> exists in destination. [INFO] ehcache-2.8.3.jar already exists in
> destination. [INFO] hsqldb-1.8.0.10.jar already exists in destination.
> [INFO] httpmime-4.4.1.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> commons-jexl-1.1.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> atlassian-html-encoder-1.4.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> jackson-1.0.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> powermock-api-mockito-1.6.2.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> spring-dao-2.0.6.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> atlassian-renderer-8.0.5.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> servlet-api-2.3.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> spring-security-core-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar already exists in destination.
> [INFO] atlassian-plugins-osgi-events-4.1.0-m002.jar already exists in
> destination. [INFO] objectweb-datasource-1.4.3.jar already exists in
> destination. [INFO] jdom-1.0.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> lucene-extras-3.3.0-atlassian-3.jar already exists in destination.
> [INFO] atlassian-rest-parent-2.9.8.pom already exists in destination.
> [INFO] jotm-1.4.3.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> atlassian-scheduler-core-1.7.0.jar already exists in destination.
> [INFO] batik-awt-util-1.7.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> jira-attachment-dmz-7.1.6.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> sal-spi-3.0.3.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> atlassian-scheduler-api-1.7.0.jar already exists in destination.
> [INFO] batik-xml-1.7.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> atlassian-threadlocal-1.3.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> atlassian-vcache-api-0.7.0.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> querydsl-core-4.0.7.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> datafile-1.3.3.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> spring-security-crypto-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar already exists in
> destination. [INFO] velocity-1.6.4-atlassian-7.jar already exists in
> destination. [INFO] atlassian-gzipfilter-legacy-1.23.0.jar already
> exists in destination. [INFO] atlassian-spring-1.1.jar already exists
> in destination. [INFO] embedded-crowd-api-2.8.3.jar already exists in
> destination. [INFO] jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.9.jar already exists in
> destination. [INFO] atlassian-landlord-spi-2.0.7.jar already exists in
> destination. [INFO] org.apache.felix.framework-4.2.1.jar already
> exists in destination. [INFO] commons-discovery-0.2.jar already exists
> in destination. [INFO] javax.mail-api-1.5.4.jar already exists in
> destination. [INFO] atlassian-secure-utils-3.2.3.jar already exists in
> destination. [INFO] jettison-1.1.jar already exists in destination.
> [INFO] jackson-jaxrs-1.9.1.jar already exists in destination. [INFO]
> xmlsec-1.4.2.jar already exists in destination. [INFO] rhino-1.7R4.jar
> already exists in destination. [INFO] batik-transcoder-1.7.jar already
> exists in destination. [INFO] atlassian-plugins-webfragment-4.1.0.jar
> already exists in destination. [INFO] sourcemap-1.7.5.jar already
> exists in destination. [INFO] atlassian-json-api-0.9.jar already
> exists in destination. [INFO] jotm-jrmp_stubs-1.4.3.jar already exists
> in destination. [INFO]  [INFO] ---
> maven-jira-plugin:6.2.3:generate-manifest (default-generate-manifest)
> @ jira --- [INFO]  [INFO] ---
> maven-jira-plugin:6.2.3:generate-test-manifest
> (default-generate-test-manifest) @ jira --- [INFO]  [INFO] ---
> maven-jira-plugin:6.2.3:validate-manifest (default-validate-manifest)
> @ jira --- [INFO] Manifest found, validating... [INFO] Manifest
> validated [INFO]  [INFO] --- maven-jira-plugin:6.2.3:jar (default-jar)
> @ jira --- [INFO] Building jar:
> /Users/strygul/dcm/jira-module/target/jira-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar [INFO] 
> [INFO] --- maven-jira-plugin:6.2.3:generate-obr-artifact
> (default-generate-obr-artifact) @ jira --- [INFO] Skipping OBR
> generation... no OSGi bundle manifest instructions found in pom.xml
> [INFO]  [INFO] --- maven-jira-plugin:6.2.3:validate-test-manifest
> (default-validate-test-manifest) @ jira --- [INFO] Manifest found,
> validating... [INFO] Manifest validated [INFO]  [INFO] ---
> maven-jira-plugin:6.2.3:test-jar (default-test-jar) @ jira --- [INFO]
> found Test: it.com.idalko.dcm.MyComponentWiredTest, adding to
> plugin.xml... [INFO] Building jar:
> /Users/strygul/dcm/jira-module/target/jira-1.0-SNAPSHOT-tests.jar
> [INFO]  [INFO] --- maven-jira-plugin:6.2.3:prepare-database
> (default-prepare-database) @ jira --- [WARNING] The property
> 'sal.version' is no longer usable to override the related bundled
> plugin.  Use <pluginArtifacts> or <libArtifacts> to explicitly
> override bundled plugins and libraries, respectively. [INFO] Missing
> configuration dataSource for pre-integration-test [INFO]  [INFO] ---
> maven-jira-plugin:6.2.3:integration-test (default-integration-test) @
> jira --- [WARNING] The property 'sal.version' is no longer usable to
> override the related bundled plugin.  Use <pluginArtifacts> or
> <libArtifacts> to explicitly override bundled plugins and libraries,
> respectively. [INFO]
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] BUILD FAILURE [INFO]
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Total time: 5.742 s [INFO] Finished at:
> 2016-10-13T22:01:10+02:00 [INFO] Final Memory: 33M/369M [INFO]
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
> com.atlassian.maven.plugins:maven-jira-plugin:6.2.3:integration-test
> (default-integration-test) on project jira: Execution
> default-integration-test of goal
> com.atlassian.maven.plugins:maven-jira-plugin:6.2.3:integration-test
> failed. NullPointerException -> [Help 1] [
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It was a problem with the version of the test plugin. Had to change it.

Comment: Extremely unusable answer.